# Laravel Eloquent - not retrieving required rows

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model, eloquent

Making use of search box on the app, database have 2 tables like below:

```
 ________________
|**Services**
 ________________
|=>id
|=>name
|=>description
|=>other_columns
________________
```

and:

```
 ________________
|**Products**
 ________________
|=>id
|=>name
|=>description
|=>service_id
|=>other_columns
________________
```

=>each **Service** contains many **Products**

=>Due to the form of the search box:

[image]

user can search for a word for `products` and **optionally** choose a service, thus, the eloquent that I use to retrieve results for:

1. if user **didn't choose a specific service** to search in:

   ```
   $data = Product::where('name','like',"%$search_value%")
           ->orWhere('description','like',"%$search_value%")
           ->orWhere('description_long','like',"%$search_value%")
           ->paginate($items_per_page);
   ```
2. if user **did choose a specific service**:

   ```
   $data = Product::where([
               ['name','like',"%$search_value%"],
               ['service_id','=',"%$service%"],
           ])
           ->orWhere([
               ['description','like',"%$search_value%"],
               ['service_id','=',"%$service%"],
           ])
           ->orWhere([
               ['description_long','like',"%$search_value%"],
               ['service_id','=',"%$service%"],
           ])
           ->paginate($items_per_page);
   ```

**Models** relations are like below:

1. **Product** Model:

   ```
   public function service(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Service::class);
   }
   ```
2. **Service** Model:

   ```
   public function products(){
       return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
   }
   ```

In both cases `$data` always contain all rows of products. how to achieve the right result?

Comment: use [whereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-exists-clauses) instead of where.

Comment: I have read the documents of `whereRaw` , but could you explain the difference?

Comment: **WhereRaw()** is a function of Laravel query builder which puts your input as it is in the SQL query's where clause.

Think of it as the **where()** function whose input argument will not be processed before inserting into queries.

Comment: Why are you using the percent signs in your `=` lines too?

Comment: It should be the same but all suggestions use this syntax: `'%'.$search_input.'%'`. Please try this out.

Comment: I've tried `'%'.$search_input.'%'` that but same result

Comment: why service_id has `%` in these `['service_id','=',"%$service%"]`? should not it be like this `['service_id','=',$service]`?

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din this is the issue, It solved the problem .. could you write it as answer to be clear to others?  plus another small issue , I'm using lorem text (**faker**) to create dummy data.. so If I search for any word it always be found i.e. searching for word **lorem**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `when()` to build dynamic queries based on your user input.

```
$data = Product::query()
    ->when($request->get('service_id') ,function($query, $service_id) {
        $query->where('service_id', $service_id);
    })
    ->where(function($query) use ($search_value) {
        $query->where(('name', 'like', "%$search_value%"))
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%$search_value%")
            ->orWhere('description_long', 'like', "%$search_value%");
    })
    ->paginate($items_per_page);
```

By nesting the full-text search conditions in another `where()` clause, we do not have to repeat the `where('service_id', $service_id)` part multiple times.

If you are using an `All Services` selection option in your frontend with `value="all"`, you can also use the following `when()` clause instead of the above:

```
->when($request->filled('service_id') && $request->get('service_id') !== 'all', function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('service_id', $request->get('service_id'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There are `%` in `['service_id','=',"%$service%"]` and it should be removed `['service_id','=',$service]`.

`%` works with `LIKE` not with `=`.

Comment: If you are looking for some way to improve your search, check out this [package](https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter)